# How to pass file as parameter to jenkins from different machines

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

I want to pass File as parameter in Jenkins. I would like to trigger the Jenkins build from remote machine and upload the file from remote machine and I am expecting Jenkins to pick the file from same machine.

But, when I tried to upload a file remote machines, it is always look up to Jenknins WorkSpace instead of taking uploaded file from remote machine.

Is there any way to configure Jenkins, it has to take same file which I have uploaded from remote machine?

I want to upload my testng.xml file from remote machines to run the scripts.

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIWKu.png)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIWKu.png)

Comment: what is the path of `testng.xml` in your workspace?

Answer (score 0):

Simply putting the file name of your file in the parameter won't lead to its usage during execution. It will just copy it in current directory of workspace and could be ignored during your build.

In the `File location` parameter, specify the relative path where you want to place this file so that it can used as intended.

Update your configuration as follows:
[image: relative path]

Comment: If we provide file location here itself, what we have to upload at build time, since it showing browse option. Do we need to leave it alone?

Comment: At build time just locate your .xml file from remote site. Keeping it blank wont have negative impact

Comment: I want to pass the uploaded xml file to testng command as below : set classpath=%projectLocation%\libs\*;%projectLocation%\target\test-classes;%projectLocation%\target\classes
java org.testng.TestNG <testng.xml>.

Comment: How do I read the file paramter in batch file at runtime, since i am not using any name to file paramter. Initially I have used %fileparametername%?

Comment: you don't have to read the file parameter in batch file. You just need to place the file in a directory and hardcode this path in your batch file. This way batch file will target to file in one directory and this file will be replaced by jenkins as per your need.